# Property is getting set to null after I set it to something?

Tags: c#

I've got a custom control and one of the properties is:

```
public List<SelectionBox> Boxes { get; set; }
```

In the control constructor I have:

```
this.Boxes = new List<SelectionBox>();
this.Boxes.Add(new SelectionBox("", Color.Red));
```

Before InitializeComponent(), if I do a breakpoint here it shows that Boxes is a list of SelectionBox with 1 element.  But then inside of my OnPaint override it has been set to null with some weird behaviour, if I do the following:

```
foreach (SelectionBox box in Boxes) {}
```

It doesn't throw an error it just exits the function by there.  What am I doing wrong?

Selection box struct:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SelectionBox
{
    public string Name;
    public Color Colour;
    public Rectangle BoxRectangle;
    public bool IsActive;

    public SelectionBox(string name, Color colour)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Colour = colour;
        this.IsActive = false;
        this.BoxRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't quite enough to speculate what might be going wrong. Are there any related parts of the code that you can show?

Comment: are you sure you are using the correct instance of boxes?

Comment: Can you show your SelectionBox Class?

Comment: Added, yes I don't see how I could be using the incorrect instance.  And I'm not sure what else would be useful Destrictor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to track down how a property is mysteriously getting its value set to null, rewrite the property with explicit get/set implementations, drop a breakpoint in the setter, and check out the callstack when the breakpoint is hit

```
private List<SelectionBox> _boxes;
public List<SelectionBox> Boxes { get { return _boxes; } set { _boxes = value; } }
```

Comment: Thanks, should of done that before I posted this really.  For some reason my main form was setting it to null.  this.dragControlTest.Boxes = null; was inside of the main form's InitializeComponent().